# MongoDb: Connection errors after upgrade

Tags: node.js, mongodb, logging, database-connection

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and recently upgraded my MongoDb server from version 4.2.3 to 4.4.14. Now I am receiving lots of error messages regarding connection aborts. They look like this:

```
{
  "t": {"$date": "2022-06-01T00:00:00.000+00:00"},
  "s": "I",
  "c": "NETWORK",
  "id": 22989,
  "ctx": "conn33041",
  "msg": "Error sending response to client. Ending connection from remote",
  "attr": {
    "error": {
      "code": 6,
      "codeName": "HostUnreachable",
      "errmsg": "Connection reset by peer"
    },
    "remote": "a.b.c.d:p",
    "connectionId": 33041
  }
}
```

I don't understand where these messages are coming from. Is this an actual error in the code? If so: How can I locate and fix it? I am accessing MongoDb via NodeJs driver.

As these messages where not logged before, is the message incorrect/misleading? If so: Can I suppress it somehow?

**Edit:** Here are the two messages from the same connection (I used a more recent one, that's why the IDs don't match. But they all look the same):

```
{
  "t": { "$date": "2022-06-07T15:25:02.030+02:00" },
  "s": "I",
  "c": "NETWORK",
  "id": 51800,
  "ctx": "conn82426",
  "msg": "client metadata",
  "attr": {
    "remote": "a.b.c.d:p",
    "client": "conn82426",
    "doc": {
      "driver": {
        "name": "nodejs",
        "version": "4.6.0"
      },
      "os": {
        "type": "Linux",
        "name": "linux",
        "architecture": "x64",
        "version": "5.4.0-48-generic"
      },
      "platform": "Node.js v14.19.2, LE (unified)|Node.js v14.19.2, LE (unified)"
    }
  }
}
{
  "t": { "$date": "2022-06-07T15:25:22.585+02:00" },
  "s": "I",
  "c": "-",
  "id": 20883,
  "ctx": "conn82426",
  "msg": "Interrupted operation as its client disconnected",
  "attr": { "opId": 7476646 }
}
```

Comment: it looks like network error

Comment: But this runs on a test system where the database resides on the same machine as the application.

Comment: what driver version are you using?

Comment: I am still on version 3.7.3. I haven't thought of this. Might it be too old? According to the [compatibility matrix](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/compatibility/#mongodb-compatibility) it should still work. I also checked the connections and I am using `useUnifiedTopology` and `useNewUrlParser` for all of them.

Comment: Could you add 2-3 previous entries in the log to give some context. Closed connection is usually a reaction to an exceptional situation. Can be anything - network error, a bug in a driver, application error etc.

Comment: I upgraded the driver to the most recent one 4.6.0. But I still get the same messages. I also added some context to the error message to the question.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen these log messages as well in my PSA cluster, after i upgraded to 4.4.16 (from 4.2.22, where i never saw them) and continuing all the way up to 5.0.14. I'm using java driver 4.3.x and 4.7.x.

I believe it's related to: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-60647

I wish i had more information or a solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).